# How to disable Thunderbird Migration Assistant after upgrade from 2.0 to 3.1

Tags: thunderbird

Is there any way to disable Thunderbird Migration Assistant after upgrade from Thunderbird 2.0 to 3.1?

The defaults there are sensible, but my users will likely be confused by this Assistant and for example choose to enable caching of IMAP folders, which will wreak havoc in roaming profiles and backups.

Disabling of options which do not make sense in corporate environment I can just append to user's prefs.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this. The trick was to remove a line containing `mailnews.ui.threadpane.version` from `prefs.js` file.

I've then added there the following lines:

```
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);
user_pref("browser.cache.disk.capacity", 0);
user_pref("mail.openMessageBehavior.version", 1);
user_pref("mail.server.default.autosync_offline_stores", false);
user_pref("mailnews.database.global.indexer.enabled", false);
user_pref("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2);
user_pref("network.cookie.prefsMigrated", true);
```

And then it started without Migration Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a user and not a programmer. V 3.1.2 is a nightmare with this function. I customized the toolbar with the functions I'm used to and for the time being I'm not using the functions on the migration assistant toolbar. Migration assistant locks the messages and cannot be deleted by these functions anyway.